# Phrase often used by waiters when the patron is leaving

Tags: méxico, saludos, identificación-de-término

I hear this phrase often from waiters at restaurants when a patron is leaving, but they say it so quickly that I can't recognize what they say; it seems that the last word is "bien" and the whole phrase consists of 2-3 words.
Any ideas?

Comment: que le vaya bien, que esté bien, etc.

Comment: @aris sounds like the first one. Why don't make it an answer?

Comment: *Que le vaya bien* -- definitely.  It's as ubiquitous as "Enjoy the rest of your day" has become recently in the US -- or more, even. To a tourist or obvious foreigner, it might be *Que te vaya bien.* // Don't be shy about asking people to repeat, more slowly, or even to write down what they said.

Answer (score 1):

> **"Que le vaya bien"** literally means ***"Farewell"***

in some places people still use

> **"Vaya con Dios"** for the same purpose which is equivalent to ***"Godspeed"***

Its an ubiquitous phrase to use when parting ways with someone you don't really know or are close with, hence the formal mode *"Que **le** vaya bien"* instead of the informal *"que **te** vaya bien"*

Why would a server bid farewell to his patron? (Something i've rarely seen in the states, but it's an everyday occurrence in mexico.)

Well , It's simply good manners, a show gratitude for the tips received, and plain good business practice.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como [indicó aris en los comentarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/phrase-often-used-by-waiters-when-the-patron-is-leaving#comment57210_31998), puede tratarse de distintas opciones:

- Que le vaya bien
- Que esté bien

As [indicated by aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/phrase-often-used-by-waiters-when-the-patron-is-leaving#comment57213_31998):

> Que le vaya bien -- definitely. It's as ubiquitous as "Enjoy the rest of your day" has become recently in the US -- or more, even. To a tourist or obvious foreigner, it might be Que te vaya bien.

Comment: añado respuesta en modo wiki para que se vean los comentarios dados bajo la pregunta